# wordpress query to get all images from a post type randomly

Tags: wordpress

i have the following query to get all images from the "myportfoliotype" post type which works fine.

However i would like all images pulled in to be random when the page is loaded / refreshed.

I followed a few tutorials, and came up with the following code:

```
<?php
 $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'myportfoliotype', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'rand' ) );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while($query->have_posts()){

        $query->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
        $image_query = new WP_Query( array('post__not_in' => array (MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('myportfoliotype', 'logo'), $thumb_id ), 'orderby' => 'rand' , 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ) );
        while( $image_query->have_posts() ) {
            $image_query->the_post();
            $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
            //echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID() );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_the_ID(), 'large');?>


    <li> <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image[0]; ?>&amp;w=137&amp;h=137&f=2" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="grey"/></a>
          <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image[0]; ?>&amp;w=200&amp;h=200" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="color"/>
    </li>


<?php           
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I'm not quite sure if this is right? As mentioned before it pull in the images but not randomly....

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, Dan

Comment: Do you use WP Engine ? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_query-orderby-random-not-working

Comment: no i don't i have my own dedicated server, i have the random function working elsewhere on the site. bit of a strange one!

Comment: Please add `echo $image_query->request;` after your second loop and add the result to your question

Comment: i get the following:

SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (0,2349) AND wp_posts.post_parent = 1375 AND (post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit') ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_posts.post_date DESC
IMG_3219-700×466 IMG_3219-700×466

Comment: Well, your orderby param is ignored, please add echo `$image_query->query_vars;` after your second loop. And do you use any plugins that could hook on `posts_orderby` filter ?

Comment: found out its actually a plugin conflicting "post type order" the random fucntion sort of works now, but groups images by post id. how can i change the above query to get it all totally random?

Comment: What do you mean by *groups images by post id* ?

Comment: i have multiple iamges uploaded to a post. so when i pull in the posts, the various posts are random but the iamges are grouped together. does this amke sense?

Comment: Well, since you have these two loops, it will necessarily *groups images by post id*, you have to review your code's logic and you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a plugin that hooks on [`posts_orderby`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) filter.

If you don't want to disable this plugin, you can add `'suppress_filters'=>true` to your [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) params.

Comment: just given this ago and it didnt work. do i add this to the post query (first query) or the image query (second query)?

Comment: second query, or just disable plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, and though i would post the answer incase anyone else was having the same problem using the "post type order" plugin.

In the setting page for "post type order" there is an option called "auto sort" you need to uncheck this this, and when making a query you should add the following:

```
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'post-type-here',
              'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
              'order'     => 'ASC'
            );
```

As simple as that!

Thanks for all the help guys!